# How to change element attributes in Jest testing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jestjs

I have a filter bar written with React which has basically 3 dropdowns in it. My goal is to test whether clicking one of the dropdowns and selecting an item changes the redux state.

At the start of my app, I make an API request to pull all items which will be filtered by filter bar.
And to prevent any user apply a filter before all items loaded, I made all dropdowns disabled

Communication between dropdowns and listed items are provided by redux.

The problem is since I cannot fake redux, I try to grab the dropdowns and make them enabled by changing their properties, but changing properties doesn't make dropdowns clickable at all.

How can I achieve the behavior I want?

I've already tried to mock API request. But because the API call is fired from different component, mocking it has no use

```
it("selecting a filter updates redux store", async () => {
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = setup(FilterNav);
    const countrySelect = getByText("Country Filter");


    // Dropdown disabled
    // <a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" 
        class="dropdown-toggle nav-link disabled" role="button" 
        tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Country Filter</a>

    countrySelect.removeAttribute("aria-disabled");
    countrySelect.classList.remove("disabled");

    // Enabled
    // <a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" 
       class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" role="button">Company</a>


    fireEvent.click(countrySelect);
    // countrySelect is disabled at the beginning
    // updating state some how doesn't update the disabled attribute
    // so click becomes useless
    const targetCountry = await waitForElement(() =>
      getByLabelText("Example Country")
    );

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by breaking up the components in a better way. First, separate the data fetching (api call) from the list of dropdowns. Then, have the dropdown list component accept the data that is needed. This will allow you to easily mock the data when creating a unit test.

Once the first dropdown has its data and is enabled, this can be tested by:

```
 expect(dropdown1.prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy()
 expect(dropdown2.prop('disabled')).toBeFalsy()
 expect(dropdown3.prop('disabled')).toBeFalsy()
```

I don't think you need to update the disabled attribute. However, if this is the case you should be able to use something like .setProp()

If you're not using jest/enzyme just determine an equivalent for prop() and setProp()

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the component I fire the API call is different from the FilterBar as you suggest, the problem is "disabled" attribute of dropdowns depends on redux which I cannot find a way to mock it.

I use react-testing-library and will look for prop() and setProp() equivalent in it

Comment: Here is some info on updating using react-testing-library. It appears in most cases this is discouraged. Your problem still sounds like it could be resolved by removing the dependency. Separate redux dependencies and pass that dependency via props. (It's difficult without seeing more code) - sorry not as helpful
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/8

Comment: Thank you, I will check and write here if I find a solution